# Django debug tool bar not showing

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhQ2U.png)

I want to show debug tool bar but it looks like above..
what's wrong?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatics`?

Comment: I did that, And I finally can get desired results. Thanks alot !!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in your INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # ...
]

STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

Check you have "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates" and "APP_DIRS": True in your template config inside settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        # ...
    }
]
```

Add "debug_toolbar" to your INSTALLED_APPS settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "debug_toolbar",
    # ...
]
```

Add django-debug-toolbar’s URLs to your project’s URLconf [urls.py, or any url file:)]

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
]
```

Add the Middleware (settings.py)

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    # ...
]
```

Configure Internal IPs add this config to settings.py

```
INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]
```

Should be working now ;)

More info https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html